# Channel creating failed for hyperledger fabric. Principal deserialization failure

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I'm starting fabric under kubernetes.

I generated artifacts and crypto configs using:

```
byfn.sh -m generate
```

And put it on github:

https://github.com/Oborysenko/Separete_nodes/tree/master/k8s/channel-artifacts
https://github.com/Oborysenko/Separete_nodes/tree/master/crypto-config

After that I mounted this repository inside image and changes envs to use those files instead of standart locations.

I have created pods with

- fabric_k8s_cli_rc.yaml
- fabric_k8s_orderer_rc.yaml
- fabric_k8s_peer0_org1_rc.yaml

and they are started, but when I going to create channel I have got this error:
Log from cli:

```
root@cli-009hv:/var/hyperledger/Separete_nodes/k8s# peer channel create -o orderer-example-com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
2017-08-29 14:08:38.106 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-29 14:08:38.106 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-29 14:08:38.108 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0A8C060A074F7267324D53501280062D...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 81C39B953EBF7FFB969B253BD7BE1889C9774ADFCF972665AEDECA1972E5984B
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A0608E6EA95CD0522...114F35DE6474ADE090C55ED95293128E
2017-08-29 14:08:38.109 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: 3C9B95C261F412FBE6B16D3188AC24A4B2FEF5CC2C74E625ED2F7A3507B57204
Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST
```

Here is what I see in ORDERER log:

```
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 168 In commit adding relative sub-policy OrdererOrg/Admins to Orderer
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 169 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 16a Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 16b Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 16c Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 16d Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 16e In commit adding relative sub-policy Org1MSP/Writers to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 16f Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 170 In commit adding relative sub-policy Org1MSP/Admins to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 171 Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 172 In commit adding relative sub-policy Org1MSP/Readers to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 173 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 174 In commit adding relative sub-policy Org2MSP/Writers to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 175 Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 176 In commit adding relative sub-policy Org2MSP/Admins to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 177 Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 178 In commit adding relative sub-policy Org2MSP/Readers to Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 179 Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 17a Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 17b Returning policy OrdererOrg/Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 17c In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/OrdererOrg/Admins to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 17d Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 17e In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/Writers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 17f Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 180 In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/Admins to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 181 Returning policy BlockValidation for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 182 In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/BlockValidation to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 183 Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 184 In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/Readers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 185 Returning policy OrdererOrg/Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 186 In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/OrdererOrg/Readers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 187 Returning policy OrdererOrg/Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 188 In commit adding relative sub-policy Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 189 Returning policy Org1MSP/Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 18a In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org1MSP/Admins to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 18b Returning policy Org1MSP/Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 18c In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org1MSP/Readers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 18d Returning policy Org2MSP/Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 18e In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org2MSP/Writers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 18f Returning policy Org2MSP/Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 190 In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org2MSP/Admins to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 191 Returning policy Org2MSP/Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 192 In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org2MSP/Readers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 193 Returning policy ChannelCreationPolicy for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 194 In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/ChannelCreationPolicy to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 195 Returning policy Org1MSP/Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 196 In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/Org1MSP/Writers to Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.471 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 197 Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 198 Returning dummy reject all policy because Readers could not be found in /Application/Readers
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 199 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19a Returning dummy reject all policy because Writers could not be found in /Application/Writers
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19b Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19c Returning dummy reject all policy because Admins could not be found in /Application/Admins
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19d Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19e Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19f Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org1MSP
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a0 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org2MSP
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a1 Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a2 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a3 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a4 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org1MSP
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a5 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org2MSP
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a6 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Admins
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a7 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Writers
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a8 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Readers
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a9 Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 1aa Returning policy ChannelCreationPolicy for evaluation
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 1ab 0xc420112a20 gate 1503957329472652555 evaluation starts
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1ac 0xc420112a20 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1ad 0xc420112a20 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 1ae Creating identity instance for ID &{Org1MSP f5eccbba9e5ceaa5fdc5ec3befad4556f32d266007038c66a94823407cb825df}
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> ERRO 1af Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 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
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1b0 0xc420112a20 principal evaluation fails
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 1b1 0xc420112a20 gate 1503957329472652555 evaluation fails
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 1b2 0xc420112a20 gate 1503957329472910864 evaluation starts
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1b3 0xc420112a20 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2017-08-28 21:55:29.472 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1b4 0xc420112a20 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 1b5 Creating identity instance for ID &{Org1MSP f5eccbba9e5ceaa5fdc5ec3befad4556f32d266007038c66a94823407cb825df}
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> ERRO 1b6 Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 0a074f7267314d53501280062d2d2d2d2d424547494e202d2d2d2d2d0a4d49494347544343416343674177494241674952414d446545736834344451744749315967787336734f7377436759494b6f5a497a6a304541774977637a454c0a4d416b474131554542684d4356564d78457a415242674e5642416754436b4e6862476c6d62334a7561574578466a415542674e564241635444564e68626942470a636d467559326c7a593238784754415842674e5642416f54454739795a7a45745a586868625842735a53316a623230784844416142674e5642414d5445324e680a4c6d39795a7a45745a586868625842735a53316a623230774868634e4d5463774f4449344d6a45314d54497a5768634e4d6a63774f4449324d6a45314d54497a0a576a42624d517377435159445651514745774a56557a45544d4245474131554543424d4b5132467361575a76636d3570595445574d4251474131554542784d4e0a5532467549455a795957356a61584e6a627a45664d4230474131554541777757515752746157354162334a6e4d53316c654746746347786c4c574e766254425a0a4d424d4742797147534d34394167454743437147534d34394177454841304941424750447158383747416734767a5a3443385a4975372b2f66715857743732560a3451714c686433682b5256506879746a546c472f392f615261323342315744714b655366426778575758554a32505059483168627474326a5454424c4d4134470a41315564447745422f775145417749486744414d42674e5648524d4241663845416a41414d437347413155644977516b4d434b41494d654139654549315a72560a41587a507850393848736c2f784f716d427959423734516c30387171687976434d416f4743437147534d343942414d43413063414d455143494533516f61354a0a5847575a757167706f764f73614b6f494371666c56625a6350464d4a7164434a33684554416942782f7472416b7075565368556757697443614d684c6c4d56680a456b472f32685975745856754c43755076413d3d0a2d2d2d2d2d454e44202d2d2d2d2d0a
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 1b7 0xc420112a20 principal evaluation fails
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 1b8 0xc420112a20 gate 1503957329472910864 evaluation fails
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1b9 Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
2017-08-28 21:55:29.473 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1ba Closing Broadcast stream
2017-08-28 21:55:29.476 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 1bb Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2017-08-28 21:55:29.476 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1bc Closing Deliver stream
2017-08-29 13:04:31.258 UTC [orderer/main] Deliver -> DEBU 1bd Starting new Deliver handler
2017-08-29 13:04:31.258 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 1be Starting new deliver loop
2017-08-29 13:04:31.258 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 1bf Attempting to read seek info message
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/main] Broadcast -> DEBU 1c0 Starting new Broadcast handler
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 1c1 Starting new broadcast loop
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 1c2 Preprocessing CONFIG_UPDATE
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/configupdate] Process -> DEBU 1c3 Processing channel creation request for channel -f
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1c4 Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Proposed configuration has no application group members, but consortium contains members
2017-08-29 13:04:31.263 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1c5 Closing Broadcast stream
2017-08-29 13:04:31.265 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 1c6 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 10.244.3.79:7050->10.244.0.110:33474: read: connection reset by peer
2017-08-29 13:04:31.266 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 1c7 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2017-08-29 13:04:31.266 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1c8 Closing Deliver stream
2017-08-29 13:05:51.750 UTC [orderer/main] Deliver -> DEBU 1c9 Starting new Deliver handler
2017-08-29 13:05:51.750 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 1ca Starting new deliver loop
2017-08-29 13:05:51.750 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 1cb Attempting to read seek info message
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/main] Broadcast -> DEBU 1cc Starting new Broadcast handler
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 1cd Starting new broadcast loop
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 1ce Preprocessing CONFIG_UPDATE
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/configupdate] Process -> DEBU 1cf Processing channel creation request for channel -f
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1d0 Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Proposed configuration has no application group members, but consortium contains members
2017-08-29 13:05:51.753 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1d1 Closing Broadcast stream
2017-08-29 13:05:51.756 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 1d2 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2017-08-29 13:05:51.756 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1d3 Closing Deliver stream
```

No other channels were created so it not an issue like here:
[FABRIC returns Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707982/fabric-returns-error-got-unexpected-status-bad-request)

In this issue [FABRIC returns Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707982/fabric-returns-error-got-unexpected-status-bad-request?rq=1)
I saw that it can be issue

```
Most commonly, for channel creation, this status indicates that the submitter does not have channel creation rights
```

But how I can resolve this issue. it's not clear for me.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not signing the channel creation request.  You need to collect signatures based upon the ChannelCreationPolicy indicated in the consortium definition.  In general this defaults to an ALL policy.  This means every member of the consortium must sign the config update.  Now it seems your's says 1 required.  So either you only have 1 member in your consortium, or you have a different policy than ALL (e.g. n_of with 1 sig required).

Comment: Can you tell me where it can be configured? Is there any configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is related to the creation of the channel twice. Have you commented the following line `# command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'` in the *compose.yaml* files?

Also, could you tell how you start up your network?

Finally, are you sure that the fields of the *crypto-config.yaml* and the fields of *your files* are the same? I.e the MSP identificator, the common name and the host and domain of each node are the same?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I commented this script.sh and create channel manually.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

`./byfn.sh -m down`

Comment: Care to elaborate? Could you explain why the user is getting the error and how this command fixes it?